# How to write a SQL Query in this type of conditions

Tags: mysql, html

I am building an ecommerce website and stuck in implementing in writing SQL Query at one place because I want to implement a function where it will loop till two place  then again switch it over!! Little hard to explain Please check my code

```html
  <?php
      $ret=mysql_query("select * from products where seller_type='best' and status = 1");
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($ret))
      {?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="products best-product">
          <div class="product">
            <div class="product-micro">
              <div class="row product-micro-row">
                <div class="col col-xs-5">
                  <div class="product-image">
                    <div class="image"> <a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"> <img src="assets/images/products/p26.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div>
                    <!-- /.image -->

                  </div>
                  <!-- /.product-image -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col2 col-xs-7">
                  <div class="product-info">
                    <h3 class="name"><a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['productName']);?></a></h3>
                    <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
                    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> $<?php echo htmlentities($row['productPrice']);?> </span> </div>
                    <!-- /.product-price -->

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.product-micro-row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.product-micro -->

          </div>
          <div class="product">
            <div class="product-micro">
              <div class="row product-micro-row">
                <div class="col col-xs-5">
                  <div class="product-image">
                    <div class="image"> <a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"> <img src="assets/images/products/p27.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div>
                    <!-- /.image -->

                  </div>
                  <!-- /.product-image -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col2 col-xs-7">
                  <div class="product-info">
                    <h3 class="name"><a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"> <?php echo htmlentities($row['productName']);?></a></h3>
                    <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
                    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> $<?php echo htmlentities($row['productPrice']);?>  </span> </div>
                    <!-- /.product-price -->

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.product-micro-row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.product-micro -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Now if i use LIMIT 2 and then in next query how i will skip the first 2 which i had already used!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2` like-

```
select * from products where seller_type='best' and status = 1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2
```

In next iteration increment value of 2 to 4, then in next one 4 to 6, and so on.
So ultimately you need to make value of Offset dynamic that increases by 2 with each iteration of your loop.

```
<?php
    $recordQuery=mysql_query("select count(*) from products where seller_type='best' and status = 1");
    $totalRecords=mysql_fetch_assoc($recordQuery);
    for ($i=0; $i<totalRecords; $i+=2) {
       $ret=mysql_query("select * from products where seller_type='best' and status = 1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET " . $i);
       $row1=mysql_fetch_array($ret);
       $row2=mysql_fetch_array($ret);
?>

       <div class="item">
         <div class="products best-product">
           <div class="product">
            <!--/.use data from $row1 here -->
           </div>
          <div class="product">
            <!--/.use data from $row here -->
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I understood that part where i should put this Query before class item or before class product Check my sample code reference

Comment: At the beginning of your code. I already mentioned that your while loop as it is. So it's simply above your while loop. and For Loop will close after your existing while loop.

Comment: If i use before items then inside items i have 2 products , don't you think both will get same product name and all the details

Answer (score 0):

```
"select * from products where seller_type='best' and status = 1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2"
```

`Offset` is what you need. It tells mysql at what offset should the query start.

This is the rule to find the correct offset Dynamically:

```
(offset * limit ) - limit
```

Example You want 2 rows starting from the first row

```
(1 * 2 ) - 2 = 0
```

So your Offset is 0 and the query is Like

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE seller_type='best' and status = 1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0"
```

The first time you want to to get 2 rows starting from the third one so:

```
(2 * 2 ) - 2 = 2
```

So your Offset this time is 2 and the query is Like

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE seller_type='best' and status = 1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2"
```

The implementation is just as easy as that add the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` at the end of your sql query

Comment: Can you edit the code and tell me ?? How to implement it??

Comment: I understood that part where i should put this Query before class item or before class product Check my sample code reference

Comment: @user2018030 Before item as you are looping through items as well and by the way don't forget to use mysqli and preferably PDO.

Comment: If i use before items then inside items i have 2 products , don't you think both will get same product name and all the details

Comment: The problem is that you have repetitive product classes inside your while loop. you need only one product class and the while loop does the rest. remove the second product class.

Comment: if i remove the second product class then my all product will go in one line i dont want that , Is there  anyway that in next product class it will take next product

Comment: your html code has some problem and that's another question you should close all your blocks before the while loops close and have only one block. for more details on html question start a new question.